# how to use react-pdf with authorization?

Tags: reactjs, pdf, display

I'm have to display some pdf content in my app but the pdf source comes from the back-end and the user has to be authentificated to view the pdf. 
If I use the iframe tag the pdf renders without a problem but if I try to use react-pdf then I get a 401 unauthorized error. 
I think the iframe tag handles automatically the token for the request. 
How can I manage this with react-pdf ? 
I don't have access to the cookies/token in the front-end (it is all handled from the back-end).

My code for displaying the pdf file :

```
import { Box, Button } from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from "react-pdf";

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = new URL(
  "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.min.js",
  import.meta.url,
).toString();

interface IPdfViewerProps {
  url: string;
}

const PdfViewer = ({ url }: IPdfViewerProps) => {
  const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(0);
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);
  const [pageScale, setPageScale] = useState(1);

  function onDocumentLoadSuccess({ numPages }) {
    setTotalPages(numPages);
  }

  function handleZoomIn() {
    if (pageScale < 3) {
      setPageScale(pageScale + 0.2);
    }
  }

  function handleZoomOut() {
    if (pageScale > 0.3) {
      setPageScale(pageScale - 0.2);
    }
  }

  function handleNext() {
    if (pageNumber < totalPages) {
      setPageNumber(pageNumber + 1);
    }
  }
  function handlePrevious() {
    if (pageNumber > 0) {
      setPageNumber(pageNumber - 1);
    }
  }

  return (
    <Box className="App">
      <Box className="page-container">
        <Document file={url} onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}>
          <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} scale={pageScale} />
        </Document>
      </Box>
      <Box className="footer">
        <Box className="button-container">
          <Button onClick={handleZoomIn} disabled={pageScale >= 3}>
            Zoom +
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleZoomOut} disabled={pageScale <= 0.3}>
            Zoom -
          </Button>
        </Box>
        <Box className="page-text">
          Page {pageNumber} of {totalPages}
        </Box>
        <Box className="button-container">
          <Button onClick={handlePrevious} disabled={pageNumber === 1}>
            ‹ Previous
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleNext} disabled={pageNumber === totalPages}>
            Next ›
          </Button>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default PdfViewer;
```

Is it still possible to use react-pdf or do I need to stay with the iframe tag ? 
Is it good practice to use iframe tag to display pdf files ? 
All pdf files come from the API and not from the users.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out how to use react-pdf with authorizations. 
I missed it in the documentation.

I have to add the options withCredentials which is to false by default.

```
   <Document file={url} onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess} options={{ withCredentials: true }}>
       <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} scale={pageScale} renderTextLayer={false} />
    </Document>
```

The problem i'm facing now is that the pdf is refetched every page changes.

The pdf is in a state so I don't know why it refetch the document.